# React Antdesign Editable Table : How to Validate CellData When Render?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I write a react compoent to render an editable table:
I want all editable cell is Validate when compoment render.
like this pic :
[image]
i want to check data when cubmit(not in form. in table compoment.)
here is table when toogle:

```
const EditableRow = ({index, ...props}) => {
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    return (
        <Form form={form} component={false}>
            <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
                <tr {...props} />
            </EditableContext.Provider>
        </Form>
    );
};
...
    const toggleEdit = () => {
        setEditing(!editing);
        form.setFieldsValue({
            [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex],
        });
    };
```

Comment: Inside the useEffect, you can trigger form validation. `useEffect(() => form.validateFields(), [form])`.